# differences (if any) between Select count () from table vs select count (*) from table

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I was looking at script in Sybase when I read something like

```
    select count() from table;
```

the result it's exactly the same to

```
    select count(*) from table;
```

I'm curious, and I was looking out for  more info in google but I didn't found anything.
I suppose that `select count(*) from table` it is ANSI and `select count() from table` not, and its just another way that sybase allow to do do it.

but anyway I would like to know if there is any difference or why are two different ways to do the same.

Comment: The first one is invalid SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you men with "invalid SQL" it works exactly the same as the second one.

Comment: Then it's some speciality in Sybase - but it's incorrect syntax in standard SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/count-function.html):

```
COUNT(*) and COUNT() are semantically equivalent.
```